# Defining a function in f#

Tags: function, functional-programming, f#

In F# I can define a function like this

```
let (-+->) x y = x + y
```

and call like this

```
let z =  5 -+-> 6
```

I can even do something like this

```
let (-++->) x y z = x y z
let p = ((fun x -> fun y -> x + y) -++-> 5 ) 6
```

But why can't I do this?

```
let (nafis) x y = x + y
let p = 5 nafis 6
```

it gives me this error `Unexpected identifier in binding. Expected '=' or other token`.

Are functions like `let (-+->) x y = x + y` any special kind of function?

Comment: I would guess it's because, like in OCaml, precedence and assocativity is determined by the first symbol, and is only defined for a very limited set of symbols. Allowing alphanumeric operator names also seems very ambiguous. How do you parse `a nafis b` for example? is is a function application where `nafis` and `b` is applied to `a`, or `a` and `b` applied to the operator `nafis`?

Comment: There are discussions to extend the language to support someting like that: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/772

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lexical constraints on operators are defined in the F# specification:

**3.7 Symbolic Operators**

> User-defined and library-defined symbolic operators are sequences of
>   characters as shown below, except where the sequence of characters is
>   a symbolic keyword(§3.6).

```
regexp first-op-char= !%&*+-./<=>@^|~
regexp op-char= first-op-char | ?
token quote-op-left = 
  | <@ <@@ 
token quote-op-right =  
  | @> @@> 
token symbolic-op= 
  | ?
  | ?<-
  | first-op-charop-char* 
  | quote-op-left
  | quote-op-right
```

as you can see, `-++->` is valid, while `nafis` is not.